# When installing, how can I have multiple mount points on a single partition?

Tags: installation, ssd, mountpoint

I want to put /home, /var, /opt and /tmp on /dev/sda2 and /root on /dev/sda1 when installing Ubuntu.

My PC has an 8GB integrated SSD, and I would like to use it to speed up boot time and application loading, but I want to save everything else onto a single partition.

I do not want to put /home, /var, /opt and /tmp on separate partitions.

Is this feasible? How do I go about accomplishing this? Something with symlinks?

Comment: What about everything else? Where should that go?

Answer (score 1):

Install with just /home on the other disk, then boot into recovery mode, go to the root shell, and move those other directories to /home and replace them with symlinks to their new location in /home.

```
mv /var /home/
ln -s /home/var/ /var
```

Comment: mv: cannot move '/var/' to '/home/var': Read-only file system

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov, right, in recovery mode the fs is initially mounted ro.  `mount -o remount,rw /` to enable writes.

Comment: I've done this and got the next msg on tty1 during the booting Ubuntu: `login: acpid: can't open socket /var/run/acpids.socket: No sush file  or directory`

Comment: If I check in root console in recovery mode `ls -la /var` it shows `/var -> /home/var/` but my guess these links are missing somehow when pc boots in normal mode. Could it be?

Comment: there was a typo in..., here is correct message `login: acpid: can't open socket /var/run/acpid.socket: No sush file  or directory` Sorry

Comment: sorry, I just realized that I moved /var to /home/myuser/ not just to /home/ to which symlink referred